# Android: Create a ColorDrawable object without using xml

Tags: android, resources

Is it possible to create a ColorDrawable object without using xml?  I would like to be able to change the backgroundColor of a view programmatically, using setBackgroundColor() or setBackgroundDrawable() or setBackgroundResource(), but I want to be able to specify the RGB values in code, not XML.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can get a View as a Drawable and apply a color filter to it (useful for coloring in Button views) by doing the following:

```
Drawable d_delete = findViewById(R.id.btn_delete).getBackground();
PorterDuffColorFilter filter_red = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
d_delete.setColorFilter(filter_red);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the questions it's a bit old but I've got an easy one. Maybe someone arrive here looking for the answer

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view_with_colored_background);
String rgbColor = "#CCFFCC";
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(rgbColor));
```